# HTML: Cut the border edges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate the design in the picture

[image: picture]

I tried to make it done with border-radius property, but was not able to replicate it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a background gradient to accomplish this:

```css
.border-red-bottom {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px 10px 40px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(-3deg, #fff 0%,#fff 40%,#f00 41%,#f00 41%,#f00 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="border-red-bottom">Notifications</div>
```

Comment: Perfect working

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is with a `clip-path`.

I've added an example of how this works, but it basicly allows you to hide part of the element using shapes, in this case a polygon.

You provide the four points of the polygon,

`0 0` top left

`100% 0` top right

`100% 48%` about half way down the right hand side

`0 100%` bottom left

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width:300px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 48%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 48%, 0 100%);
  padding:10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your red element:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 100% 80%, 100% 93%, 0% 100%);
```

You can adjust the values if the angle isn't perfect for you.